# Software Foundations: apply ... with ... tactic

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

I'm try to run some simple examples on `apply ... with ...` tactic from Pierce's "Software Foundations".

It seems that examples from book doesn't work for me:

```
Theorem trans_eq: forall (X: Type) (n m o: Type),
                    n = m -> m = o -> n = o.
Proof.
  intros X n m o eq1 eq2. rewrite -> eq1. rewrite -> eq2. reflexivity.
Qed.

Example trans_eq_example' : forall (a b c d e f : nat),
     [a;b] = [c;d] ->
     [c;d] = [e;f] ->
     [a;b] = [e;f].
Proof.
  intros a b c d e f eq1 eq2.
  (* If we simply tell Coq apply trans_eq at this point,
     it can tell (by matching the goal against the
     conclusion of the lemma) that it should instantiate X
     with [nat], n with [a,b], and o with [e,f].
     However, the matching process doesn't determine an
     instantiation for m: we have to supply one explicitly
     by adding with (m:=[c,d]) to the invocation of
     apply. *)
  apply trans_eq with (m:=[c;d]). apply eq1. apply eq2. Qed.
```

`trans_eq_example'` failed with error:

```
trans_eq_example' < apply trans_eq with (m:=[c;d]).
Toplevel input, characters 6-30:
> apply trans_eq with (m:=[c;d]).
>       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: Impossible to unify "?1707 = ?1709" with "[a; b] = [e; f]".
```

Additional information about Coq version:

```
coqtop -v
The Coq Proof Assistant, version 8.4pl4 (July 2014)
compiled on Jul 27 2014 23:12:44 with OCaml 4.01.0
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: As I don't have the Software Foundation source code at hand, could you give us the notation for what ``[a;b]`` stands for ? Is it lists ?

Comment: The error seems to be quite trivial. In `trans_eq`, `n`, `m` and `o` must be of type `X`, not of type `Type`. Note that currently `X` is not used in your theorem.

Comment: Damned @eponier, your beat me by 1min :) you should post answers in the Answer section.

Comment: @Vinz I hesitated, because it is a particular case. I post an answer when I have more interesting things to write. I am not sure if it is a question general enough to be kept on SO. At least, I would suggest to change the title to reflect the actual problem.

Comment: I agree, the title should be corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not the `apply` but a typo in your previous code. The definition of `trans_eq` should be:

```
Theorem trans_eq: forall (X:Type) (n m o: X), n = m -> m = o -> n = o.
```

Note that the type of `n m o` should be `X`, not `Type`.